# use Unigui with mORMot

Tags: json, frameworks, mormot

I have tested Unigui, as Web Server,and i have used Mormot as DB Server

I found this two framework amazing,

My Question : is there possibility to use Unigui to have beautiful Ajax Browser 
and mORMot as DB Server

Cans I merge  Unigui and mORMot in same Project ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly possible.

See http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1281